# message.acknowledge() doesn't dequeue the messages after they have been read in ActiveMQ with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I'm trying to read queues by their id in their content and then dequeue them, using Spring Boot and ActiveMQ Classic.

For this cause, I create the code below. Code pulls the a queue from responses according to requestId, does some operations then returns. Code grabs the queue without any issue. But it doesn't `dequeue` it from ActiveMQ.

```java
Object obj = jmsTemplate.browseSelected("responses", "requestId='"+id+"'", new BrowserCallback() {
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<OperationResultResponse> doInJms(Session session, QueueBrowser browser) throws JMSException {
        Enumeration<?> enumeration = browser.getEnumeration();
        if (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            Message message = (Message) enumeration.nextElement();
            
            // process the message
            if (message instanceof ActiveMQObjectMessage objectMessage){
                try{
                    // extract the requestId and put in QueueResponse object
                    QueueResponse queueResponse = (QueueResponse) objectMessage.getObject();
                    String requestId = queueResponse.getRequestId();
                    // some other operations..
                    

                    return something...;
                }catch (Exception exception){
                    // handle error
                    return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                }
            }
        }
        // Handle the case where queue not exist
        return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

To solve this, I add `message.acknowledge()` in to the `try` block and I change the `acknowledge-mode` to `client` but it didn't have any effect. I also tried to add `session.close()` but still no effect.

I traced the `acknowledge` with debugger and I noticed that in the function, `acknowledgeCallback` is `null`. Which makes the code not execute the `acknowledge` I think. I don't know how to make it non-null.

```java
public void acknowledge() throws JMSException {
    if (this.acknowledgeCallback != null) {
        try {
            this.acknowledgeCallback.execute();
        } catch (JMSException var2) {
            throw var2;
        } catch (Throwable var3) {
            throw JMSExceptionSupport.create(var3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using the [`browseSelected`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#browseSelected(jakarta.jms.Queue,java.lang.String,org.springframework.jms.core.BrowserCallback)) method from  `org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate`. The JavaDoc for this method states:

> **Browse** selected messages in a JMS queue. The callback gives access to the JMS Session and **QueueBrowser** in order to browse the queue and react to the contents. [emphasis mine]

When you inspect messages with a [`QueueBrowser`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/messaging/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/jms/queuebrowser) you *can't* remove them from the queue. The JavaDoc for `QueueBrowser` states:

> A client uses a QueueBrowser object to look at messages on a queue without removing them.

Try receiving the messages in a different way (e.g. using [`doReceive`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#doReceive(jakarta.jms.Session,jakarta.jms.Destination,java.lang.String))).